# Chances of getting 5 golden legendaries in a single pack?

Tags: hearthstone

I found [this](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/general-deck-building/398-cards-rarity-chances-on-packs) forum post about chances of getting legendaries.

Quote:

> - 1 Rare each                    0,85 to 0,90 packs
> - 1 Epic each                     +- 5 packs
> - 1 Legendary each           +- 20 packs
>
> Golden:
>
> 2% Chance of Golden Common (1 Every 50 Cards)
>
> 1% Chance of Golden Rare (1 Every 100 Cards)
>
> 0.25% Chance Golden Epic (1 Every 400 Cards)
>
> 0.05% Golden Legendary (1 Every 2000 Cards)

Where a golden legendary is 0.0005% chance per card in a pack.

I assume getting 5 golden legendaries would be `0.0005% x 0.0005% x 0.0005% x 0.0005% x 0.0005%`.

But I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe this is more of a math question?

Comment: They don't have to ALLOW this scenario to happen.  They can hard-code the game to limit to, say, 2 Legendaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the math is right.
The chances of having a golden legendary is 0.05% (1 over 2000).

So, that's exactly `0.05% x 0.05% x 0.05% x 0.05% x 0.05% = 3.125e-15%` chances that happens, *that is to say* once chance in `3.2e+14`. In other words, you have to open ***150 thousands of billions*** packs (in average) before hoping to open the 5-golden-legendaries pack. Good luck !

EDIT: The math is right if you consider no [*pity timer*](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3z7jyh/pity_timer_on_packs_opening_and_the_best_strategy/) (thanks [Rob](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291460/168120)). As Blizzard does not provide any detail about this, the straight-forward calculation gives a nice idea of the chances to have such a pack.

Comment: Just golden legendaries.

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment accidentally. Here it is again: You assume each probability of a card being a golden legendary is independent from other probabilities. If this is the case, you are right.

Comment: @Rob Yes. I assume there is no such pity timer you are talking about.

Comment: I never played the game, but this also assumes that more than one 'golden legendary' can be in the same pack.

Comment: You have to treat each card idependantly... if you have 0.25% chance of having **a pack** with a golden legendary you can't multiply that by 5 because you are taking the probability of a pack for a card. So if the first percentage is correct, 0.05%^5 would be the correct equation.

Comment: @Karlyr you are right. Edited the answer

Comment: And the "pity timer" would only affect the first card... So it wouldn't increase that much the probability. Final verdict : Go buy a lottery ticket instead of trying this. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Only considering your information you would be correct. Your information assume that any probability of a card being a (golden) legendary is independent from the probabilities of other cards.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. On [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3z7jyh/pity_timer_on_packs_opening_and_the_best_strategy/) somebody analyzed the probabilities of getting legendaries. Quote:

> The probability is increasing as the amount of packs increases and it also shows a significant gain after 30 packs.

I don't know if there is some official source confirming the existence of such a *Pity Timer* as it is called there.

Thus, the probability of getting a legendary appears not to be the same for every card and, consequently, does not seem to be independent from other probabilities. That means the calculation is probably much more complicated than just (0.05%)^5.

Comment: Nice that's exactly the stuff I wan't to find out , shame blizzard doesn't release more official data about this.

Comment: a "Pity Timer", more frequently known as "Bad Luck protection" is something that's frequent in Blizzard games that involve RNG. If something has a low chance of occuring, like the player receiving a rare item or the player triggering an effect from one of their spells with a low random chance, the chance of that event occuring increases every time something happens that can trigger that event, based on the intended frequency of that event occuring. World of Warcraft uses it to increase the chance for a player to get a random legendary, for example.

Comment: @Nzall I would be interested in some official source about that. Do you have one?

Comment: Concerning the pity timer, there is also something to take into consideration. Is the probability increase valid for the first legendary of the pack or for all the cards ? I suspect that while picking the cards, if the first one is already a legendary, the pity timer is immediately cancelled for the 4 others picks. Consequently, I guess we can say that (0.05%)^4 * X would be the correct math, where X is something between 0.05% and 1.

Comment: @Wis Perhaps, as long as the pity timer doesn't start to increase the probability in between a legendary and the 4th subsequent card.

Comment: It's also possible that the *number of rare cards in each pack* itself is artificially limited. This to make every pack generally equally valuable

Comment: @Nzall it isn't even constrained to Blizzard games- many "random" elements in games are set to be pseudo-random instead of actual random. As an example, many games' "critical hit" mechanics aren't a true percent, but rather they start at a slightly lower percent and gain until you get a critical- i.e. they're bounded such that a 50% critical chance relates much more consistently to "every other hit is critical" instead of the random approach where 50% of all your things are critical, which could easily contain a series of 10 not-criticals followed by 10 criticals.

Comment: Considering if the pity timer actually exists does it really inflict with the chance of getting 5 golden legendaries or does it perhaps only guarantee a legendary.

Comment: @RyadShaanbi If the pity timer really exists and does influence all 5 cards in a pack, we would have seen some 5 golden legendary draws, I guess. My proposal is to stop speculating.

Comment: @Rob http://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/8197741003 explains how Bad Luck Protection works for RPPM trinkets, the first system with this random element that got this kind of protection. https://twitter.com/wowhead/status/743509560762064896 is a tweet from a fansite that highlights a message from a Twitch Q&A from that day, available on youtube. If I had the time for it, I could probably look up all other systems where that's known to be used.